# Screen rotation bug in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Hello everyone I am new in Sherlock Actionbar I am having a very strange problem in my sample application. The problem is that when I rotate to landscape from the portrait its behavior is normal but when I rotate back to portrait mode the layout does not change back to portrait mode.

Below are the screen shot of the problem I am facing.

**OriginalScreen**
[image]

**Did rotation to Landscape**
[image]

**Again rotated back to original orientation i.e. Portrait Mode**
[image]

As you can see that on the third picture the problem I am facing.

I am using the latest version of ActionbarSherlock library.

**Edited**
My manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.actionbar_sherlockexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.actionbar_sherlockexample.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks

Comment: show us your android manifest file.. have you used android:confing???

Comment: @ Dhawal Sodha I have edited my question you can see my manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with emulator . If you will run it on real device , it will work fine .

Comment: Usually it happens with Emulators version 3.0 and above on x64 operating systems.